# Android testers not receiving application update

Tags: android, google-play

I have published multiple apk android aplication. First apk is with versionCode 10106 and second apk with version 14106.

Now, i have updated application and made changes so that i dont have two apk files, but one single apk for all API's. VersionCode of new apk is 19112.

Application is published to Alpha section. None of my testers received update yet. Three days passed. I have received update 2hrs after publish, so i do not think is GooglePlay store fault.

I am using Nexus5 with Android L developer preview installed. And i am sure that some of my testers have 4.4.4 KitKat on ther phones, but again it does not make sense, because it says that there are 6324 supported devices.

Below you can see my build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 19112
    versionName '1.1.2'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-       project.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

This is a warning i have on PlayStore:

```
A device with API levels in range 14+ is eligible to receive version 14106, which is optimized for higher API levels, but actually receives version 19112 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when 
Release track containing any of [BETA] and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
OpenGL ES versions in range 2.0+ and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].

A device upgrading from API levels in range 10-13 to API levels in range 14+ would become eligible to receive version 14106, which is optimized for higher API levels, but would actually receive version 19112 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when 
Release track containing any of [BETA] and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
OpenGL ES versions in range 2.0+ and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].

Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.
Previously active APKs supported more devices than those in the draft configuration. 

Some devices will not receive upgrades.
Devices currently running version 8100 are no longer supported by the current configuration. Such devices will not receive upgrades. 
API levels in range 8-9 and 
Release track containing any of [ALPHA, BETA] and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
OpenGL ES versions in range 2.0+ and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN]
```

Comment: Do your testers have automatic updates enabled in the play store? Have they tried manually checking for an update?

Comment: @Tanis.7x Automatic updates are mostly turned off, but i have tried with three of my testers manual update and all of them get old, 1.0.9 version. Also, i have sent apk file to one of my testers, and application is running without any issues. Then she tried to download version from store, and again, old 1.0.9 version is downloaded.

Comment: @bajicdusko I have a similar issue, people do not get the update. on some phone I get a notification about the update, but even if "auto-update" is enabled, it doesn't update automatically, users has to manually update. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @sonique if you have published your app to alpha channel, try to switch it to beta, once you do that it should work..

Comment: @bajicdusko, actually the app is live, and users doesn't get the update automatically, they have to manually update.